# How to fix / debug 'expected x.rb to define X.rb' in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have seen this problem arise in many different circumstances and would like to get the best practices for fixing / debugging it on StackOverflow.

To use a real world example this occurred to me this morning:

```
expected announcement.rb to define Announcement
```

The class worked fine in development, testing *and* from a production console, but failed from in a production Mongrel. Here's the class:

```
class Announcement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attachment :content_type => 'audio/mp3', :storage => :s3
end
```

The issue I would like addressed in the answers is not so much solving this specific problem, but how to properly debug to get Rails to give you a meaningful error as expected x.rb to define X.rb' is often a red herring...

**Edit (3 great responses so far, each w/ a partial solution**)

**Debugging:**

1. From Joe Van Dyk: Try accessing the model via a console on the environment / instance that is causing the error (in the case above: script/console production then type in 'Announcement'.
2. From Otto: Try setting a minimal plugin set via an initializer, eg: config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ] then re-enable one at a time.

**Specific causes:**

1. From Ian Terrell: if you're using attachment_fu make sure you have the correct image processor installed. attachment_fu will require it even if you aren't attaching an image.
2. From Otto: make sure you didn't name a model that conflicts with a built-in Rails class, eg: Request.
3. From Josh Lewis: make sure you don't have duplicated class or module names somewhere in your application (or Gem list).

Comment: I've been having the same problem with rake tasks in production. Here is the best solution I've found: http://www.spacevatican.org/2008/12/28/when-cache_classes-gets-you-down/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is a tricky one.

What generally works for me is to run "script/console production" on the production server, and type in:

`Announcement`

That will usually give you a better error message.  But you said you already tried that?

Comment: Good start, worth an up vote. But how do you debug the case where the error is only occurring via Mongrel?

Comment: I'm using no plugins and I have this error in development mode.

Comment: Giving an up-vote, is not enough, you just saved me! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this error as well.

The short of it was that my rb file in my lib folder was not in a folder structure to match my module naming convention.  This caused the ActiveSupport auto loader to use the wrong module to see if my class constant was defined.

Specifically I had defined the following class

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end
```

In the root of /lib/bar.rb

This caused the autoloader to ask module Object if Bar was defined instead of module Foo.

Moving my rb file to /lib/foo/bar.rb fixed this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this before, and the `AttachmentFu` plugin was to blame.  I believe in my case it was due to `AttachmentFu` expecting a different image processor than what was available, or non-supported versions were also installed.  The problem was solved when I explicitly added `:with => :rmagick` (or similar -- I was using RMagick) to the `has_attachment` method call *even for non-image attachments.*   Obviously, make sure that your production environment has all the right gems (or freeze them into your application) and supporting software (ImageMagick) installed.  YMMV.

As for not getting Rails and AttachmentFu to suck up and hide the real error -- we fixed it before figuring it out completely.

Comment: Good extra info, but not a complete answer... I believe using joevandyk's technique of testing from a console would have given you a better error message.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is still the top Google result, I thought I'd share what fixed the problem for me:

I had a module in the lib folder with the exact same name as my application.  So, I had a conflict in module names, but I also had a conflict of folder names (not sure if the latter actually makes a difference though).

So, for the OP, make sure you don't have duplicated class or module names somewhere in your application (or Gem list).

Answer (score 2):

For me, the cause was a circular dependency in my class definitions, and the problem only showed up using autotest in Rails.  In my case, I didn't need the circular dependency, so I simply removed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try disabling all your plugins and add them back in one by one.

In `environment.rb` in the Initalizer section, add a line like this one:

```
config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]
```

Start with the minimum set to run your application and add them in one by one.  I usually get this error when I've defined a model that happens to map to an existing filename.  For example, a Request model but Rails already has a request.rb that gets loaded first.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem for a while and in my case the error was always preceded from this S3 error:

> (AWS::S3::Operation Aborted) "A
>   conflicting conditional operation is
>   currently in progress against this
>   resource. Please try again."

This problem usually occurs when creating the same bucket over and over again. (Source [AWS Developers forum](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/message.jspa?messageID=103933#103933))

This was due to the fact that I had used `attachment_fu to` create the bucket and I had decommented the line containing the command `Bucket.create(@@bucket_name)` in `lib/technoweenie/attachment_fu/backends/s3_backends.rb` (near to line 152).

Once commented or deleted the command `Bucket.create(@@bucket_name)` the problem disappeared.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Changing class names while using STI caused this for me:

- Class changed from 'EDBeneficiary' to 'EdBeneficiary'
- Existing records had 'EDBeneficiary' stored in the 'type' column, so when Rails tried to load them up the exception was raised.

Fix: Run a migration to update values in the 'type' column to match the new class name.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I am getting this error in the development console but I can load the class in irb

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this isn't a definitive answer, but another approach that might work in some specific circumstance:

I just ran in to this problem while debugging a site using Ruby 1.8.7 and Merb 1.0.15. It seemed that the class in question (let's call it SomeClass) was falling out of scope, but when some_class.rb file was automatically loaded, the other files it required (some_class/base.rb etc) were not loaded by the require mechanism. Possibly a bug in require?

If I required some_class file earlier, such as the end of environment.rb, it seems to prevent the object falling out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error duo to a controller definition being in a file that wasn't named as a controller. For instance, you have a Comment model and you define the controller in a comment.rb file instead of comments_controller.rb

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with rails version 1.2.3. I could reproduce the problem only with mongrel, using console environment access didn't give any useful info. In my case, I solved making the RAILS_ROOT/html folder writable by mongrel and then restarting the web server, as some users reported here:

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/77708

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded rails from 1.1.6 to 1.2.6 and 2.0.5 for my app, I faced this error. In short, old plugins caused this error. These plugins were already out-dated and no update anymore (even no repo!). After I removed them, the app worked on 1.2.6 and 2.0.5. But I didn't check the detail source code of the plugins.